# How to make draggable Radwindow?

Tags: telerik, radwindow

I'm working with telerik controls. currently, I'm struck with RadWindow control with dragging.

ISSUE : Dragging is not working for me.

Kindly give some suggestion for the issue.

CODE :

```
<telerik:RadWindow RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" Width="600" Height="300" RestrictionZoneID="RestrictionZoneID" EnableTheming="true" Modal="True" InitialBehaviors="Close" Behaviors="Close" VisibleStatusbar="false" OnClientClose="OnClientClose" Skin="MetroTouch" IconUrl="~/styles/images/30x30_edit_ring_white.png">
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Behaviors` property to include `Move`

```
<telerik:RadWindow ... Behaviors="Close, Move"...>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/getting-started/user-interaction-with-the-window

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/behaviors/defaultcs.aspx